# Turn off @Generate annotation in MapStruct

Tags: java, mapstruct

I want to disable @Generate annotation in generated (by mapstruct) classes.

I try args
`-Amapstruct.suppressGeneratorTimestamp=true`
and
`-Amapstruct.suppressGeneratorVersionInfoComment=true`, but it's still do not turn off annotation.

In the source code of mapstruct I found class `GeneratedType`, which has in constructor declare a field `generatedTypeAvailable`, which affect on a template `GeneratedType.ftl`:

```
<#if !generatedTypeAvailable>/*</#if>
@Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor"<#if suppressGeneratorTimestamp == false>,
    date = "${.now?string("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")}"</#if><#if suppressGeneratorVersionComment == false>,
    comments = "version: ${versionInformation.mapStructVersion}, compiler: ${versionInformation.compiler}, environment: Java ${versionInformation.runtimeVersion} (${versionInformation.runtimeVendor})"</#if>
)<#if !generatedTypeAvailable>
*/</#if>
```

So, how to set field value `generatedTypeAvailable` to `false` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it is not possible to disable the creation of the `@Generated` annotation. Why do you need to do that?

What you can do is to:

- Suppress the timestamp value using `-Amapstruct.suppressGeneratorTimerstamp=true`
- Suppress the version using `-Amapstruct.suppressGeneratorVersionInfoComment`

Comment: It would be useful if one wanted to include the mapstruct implementation in your test coverage. Although the code is generated (and therefore one typically would not want to test it), there is a fair degree of business logic underneath that one may want to enforce testing on.

Comment: Same argument here: I would like to ensure full code coverage of the generated code that's part of MapStruct. However since Jacoco does not allow to override it's skipping of @Generated sources, and MapStruct does not allow to suppress generation off this annotation, it's impossible to do so.